# errror 503 in host /opt/alt/python310/bin/lswsgi: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

I uploaded my python project to the host and made the necessary database settings and things, but it still gives me a 503 error. When I look at the log file, I get the following error. Please, if anyone knows, I would appreciate it.

/usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi_wrapper: line 18: /opt/alt/python310/bin/lswsgi: No such file or directory

install packeges mysqlclient migrate settengs database allwed_host and passenger_wsgi , I did all these things, but the site did not load

Comment: this file (or directory) does not exist.

Comment: what folder Do you think it has anything to do with this file lswsgi?